# Reading excel attachment on itemAdded event

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to read excel file which is uploaded on itemadded event. I need to update meta data column of document library by reading uploaded excel sheet. But I get following error,

[image]

Here is my code,

```
   SPItem item = properties.ListItem;

   string workbookpath = "http://server/sites/dev/Published%20documents/Test.xlsx";
   ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
   excel.Visible = false;

   Workbook excelWorkBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbookpath, 0, true, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

   Sheets sheets = excelWorkBook.Worksheets;
   Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
   Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");

   item["Status"] = (string)range.Cells.Value2;

   item.Update();

   base.ItemAdded(properties);
```

For testing purpose I've hard coded the excel file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post. I think it will help

http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/uploading-a-file-event-receivers-the-file-has-been-modified-by/

Comment: But SPItem doesn't has "SystemUpdate()" method. How to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you document is in checked out state because you have open it from excel app, so you need to do following:

1. close excel app
2. Check in document back to save chages or undo check out (use `item.CheckIn()` or `item.UndoCheckOut()`)

after this you should be able to update item properties